# Javascript/CSS Floating Labels

Tags: javascript, css, forms, label

I am having a really weird issue and can't seem to figure out if I'm looking at a javascript or css issue. Here is a [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njjZr/) for some context of what I am talking about. If you type in the input box and don't see a label popup, delete the text and type it again...weird huh?

I have a form that can be viewed either directly, or in an iFrame. On the inputs, I am using [jvfloat.js](https://github.com/maman/JVFloat.js) to give floating labels using the `placeholder` values.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('input').jvfloat();
});
```

I get different results across browsers (current releases) and also, oddly enough, when in an iFrame or not.

**Chrome**

*In IFrame:*

> Typing in text field doesn't popup label. Inspection shows "activeLabel" class added successfully, but it doesn't seem to render. Seems like a CSS transform isn't working to move the label up from  behind the input.

*Outside IFrame:*

> Works as expected.

**Firefox**

*In IFrame / Outside IFrame:*

> Works as expected

I haven't tried it in any other browsers. Every now and then the labels don't work and I can't repeat the problem consistently.

In the jsFiddle, can you see any major problems with the javascript or CSS that would cause this weird behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS issue.

You're using `display`, `visibility`, and `opacity` to show/hide your floating placeholder. That's overkill, you only need one!  I get `opacity`, you need it for the effect.

I dropped any use of `visibility`, and it now works:

http://jsfiddle.net/njjZr/3/

Comment: Awesome! I was just using the CSS that came with the plugin. I figured he had a good reason for using all three. Thanks.